# Application not connecting to Mongoose Database

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am having trouble connecting to my mongoose database. I just don't know if something is wrong with my code or if I need to install more mongoose packages. Or possibly reinstall everything. Can anyone tell me what the issue is?

The problematic lines are:

```
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://node:node@novus.modulusmongo.net:27017/Iganiq8o'); // connect to our database
```

Is the application supposed to connect to the database automatically? Or do I need to run mongod in the background? My application runs perfectly and connects to the server without those lines. And here is the error from the command prompt:

[image]

Can someone please explain what the error is and how I can fix it? I don't understand what it says here. Thanks so much.

Full code:

```
// server.js

// BASE SETUP
// =============================================================================

// call the packages we need
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        // set our port


var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://node:node@novus.modulusmongo.net:27017/Iganiq8o'); // connect to our database

// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================
var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the express Router

// test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });
});

// more routes for our API will happen here

// REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------------------
// all of our routes will be prefixed with /api
app.use('/api', router);

// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you used [this blog](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) post as a reference. I did it as well, and it didn't connected to my Modulus database as I expected, I double checked the user and password to see if nothing was wrong and tried to connect using mongo shell from my machine with:

`mongo jello.modulusmongo.net:27017/your_url -u <user> -p <pass>`

And it worked, so I was puzzled and discovered that what solves the problem is an upgrade in mongoose to `3.8.0` instead of the used `3.6.13` and it worked flawlessly, it connects to the Modulus database, although I don't know what happens or why it happens, it must be something with mongoose.

Comment: Updating the version of the mongoose (`"mongoose": "~4.4.19",`) worked for me

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that the DB your application is trying to connect has different username password combination. You need the correct user/pass combination.

Your code will work without those two lines, but your applicaiton will not have DB support.

Optionally you could proceed with running mongodb locally. A standard way would be to running the monogod.exe and creating your DB and changing the `mongoose.connect('mongodb://node:node@novus.modulusmongo.net:27017/Iganiq8o')` to `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/<your-db>')` . Please note the db in this case has no security(user/pass).

Comment: Does it matter which Database I use? I created a Modulus database and that too is not working, with my username and password combination. Should it be MongoLab? Is there a difference between the code for those two databases?

Comment: Mongoose.js can only be used with MongoDB database. It doesn't matter if its mongolab or Modulus or any other cloud as long its a MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks like you are trying to connect a database which is not in your MongoDB.
I also encountered the same problem and get solved by doing as follows:

- Created a database in mongo.
- Changed the path to
  `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name');`
- Started the MongoDB using the command mongo.

Answer (score 0):

The error is about authentication in mongoDB 'MongoError: auth fails'.

Maybe the user:pass 'node:node' didn't exist in your local database, check if that user exist in your mongoDB, or create a specific one with the user:pass you want .

See [getUsers docs of mongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getUsers/)

Good luck!